# Text drawing is taking a lot on iPad using iOS 4.2 gm seed

Tags: ios, drawing, ipad, ios-4.2

I wrote an app which draws some text on the view using my own custom fonts, and the drawing takes about 200 ms on iPad with iOS 3.2, but after I installed iOS 4.2 BETA a month ago, it took more than 2 to 3 seconds to draw (10 - 15 times more), at that time I thought it's a BETA problem so I rolled back to iOS 3.2, then yesterday I installed the 4.2 GM Seed (which is considered as a final release) and the same problem happened,

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Thank you for your help and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the Sampler tool in Instruments.app (/Developer/Applications/Instruments.app) to determine where your time is being spent.  Then you'll know what is actually slow, and you can optimize what you need to.

Comment: I told you where it's, with the actual drawing methods that uses Core Graphics... Anyway I found some other guys who have the same issue with drawing in iOS 4 on older devices (like iPad)